# Jquery put elements in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

You need to put items in a div - `<div style = 'flex-direction: column;'>`.

Div needs to be created after `p` with`id = "billing_city_field"`
and closes after the `p` with`id = "apartment_field"`.
Tried to do it with this function:

```
 jQuery (document) .ready (function ($) {
     $ ("# billing_city_field"). after ("<div style = 'flex-direction: column;'>");
     $ ("# apartment_field"). after ("</ div");
 });
```

But the div immediately closes. What should I do?

Comment: There's no such thing as `</div>` elements. You're operating on DOM elements, not HTML text.

Comment: So when you add a `<div>`, it's automatically closed, you don't need to add `</div>` explicitly.

Comment: This is right behavior.  To reach your goal you have to move #appartment_field inside the div you just created. To do it first create div with some ID. And use jquery append() function to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot append start/end tags separately. The DOM works with elements as a whole, so you need to create the entire `div` element in a single operation.

Given the description of your goal it looks like you're trying to wrap the existing content in a new div. As such you can use `nextUntil()` (assuming the target elements are siblings) and then `wrapAll()`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $contents = $("#billing_city_field").nextUntil('#apartment_field').add('#apartment_field');
  $contents.wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
});
```

Note the use of a `class` attribute in the above example, instead of applying inline `style` rules.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I need 1 div for all elements, not 1 div for each elements

Comment: Then you can use `wrapAll()`. I updated the example in the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Question is not super clear but from what I can tell.
I think you have small misunderstanding what `.after` does with jQuery. After in this case is "structural" and not "time" related. If you check jQuery docs (https://api.jquery.com/after/) for this you can see basically what you need to do.

Simplest way to do this, if these things needs to created and don't exist already on `body` for example.

```js
$(function(){
   var p = $("<p id='apartment_field'>Paragraph test</p>");
   $("body").append("<div id='billing_city_field' style='flex-direction: column;'></div>");
   $("#billing_city_field").html(p);
});
```

I've added `Paragraph test` so result is visible easier.

And one more thing, not sure if it's error with copy/paste but make sure that `#` and `id` don't have space in-between like this.

```
$("#billing_city_field")
$("#apartment_field")
```

Edit: Looking at the comments maybe something like this, if they exist already? You should clarify the question more.

```
$("#billing_city_field").append($("#apartment_field").detach());
```